# How can i increase number of rows in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table structure

```
id name
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
```

how can i get number `rows=16` if number of records=M then resultant should be `M^2`

i tried this query to get result

```
select * from t
union
select * from t
union 
select * from t
union
select * from t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table t1 cross join table t2
```

## <kbd>[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15690)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by cross Apply

```
Select A.* from Table1 a cross apply Table1
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adefb/1)